# Has something changed with using delgated credentials in GSuite Drive API v3?

Tags: google-drive-api

I have some code that has been run on around 1000 accounts previously without this issue and all of a sudden has ceased to work.

The code handles removing accounts from gsuite and downloads drive files to a local storage for preservation.

I am using a service account with the drive v3 api.  The service account has Domain Wide Delegation and has a permission for the scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive

I delegate access to the users account through:

```
delegated_credentials = credential.create_delegated(account_name)
http = delegated_credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
service=discovery.build(api, version, http=http)
```

Error is:
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files//export?mimeType=application%2Fvnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document returned "The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file.">

Has anyone else recently started experiencing this type of issue recently?  I don't run this code very frequently and the last time was probably around 6 months ago.  I know google had the api issues with google+, maybe something has changed that I missed?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What does your code look like that doesn't work? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Jacque....... thanks for looking at this and taking time to write. After a few more hours of just staring at this I realized I had suspended the users , I unsuspended before trying to download again and it seems to work now.  I would swear under oath this worked while suspended previously but either way, I have a way forward now by ensuring the user in not suspended before trying to do the download.